# Gatsby javascript files do not load on first load, only on refresh; MIME-TYPE error

Tags: javascript, gatsby, netlify

On first load of my page, I always get this error: `Refused to execute script from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.` The result is a lot of my javascript does not work at all. If I reload the page, it works perfectly. This only happens in production via Netlify. My local environment works perfectly every time with no console errors or warnings.

Here is the dom when I get the error:

[image]

And here is the dom on second load when everything loads properly:

[image]

Lastly, here is my html.js file:

```
let stylesStr
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === `production`) {
  try {
    stylesStr = require(`!raw-loader!../public/styles.css`)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

module.exports = class HTML extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let css
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === `production`) {
      css = (
        <style
          id="gatsby-inlined-css"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: stylesStr }}
        />
      )
    }
    return (
      <html {...this.props.htmlAttributes}>
        <head>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
          />
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href={favicon} />
          {this.props.headComponents}
          {css}
        </head>
        <body {...this.props.bodyAttributes}>
          {this.props.preBodyComponents}
          <div
            key={`body`}
            id="___gatsby"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.body }}
          />
          {this.props.postBodyComponents}
          <script
            type="text/javascript"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `
                ...some javascript code
              `
            }}
          />
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}
```

I tried setting the type in the gatsby-config.js file but it did not solve the problem.

```
resolve: `gatsby-plugin-netlify`,
        options: {
          headers: {
            "/*.js": [
              "Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
              "Content-Type: text/javascript"
            ],
          },
        },
      },
```

Figured out the fix:

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-netlify`,
      options: {
        mergeLinkHeaders: false,
        mergeCachingHeaders: false
      },
    },
```

Comment: Check the Network tab of the developer tools to see what's going on with the network requests. If you make a request with `curl` does it return the correct HTML?